# Manipulating one of many?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some markup, like so...

```
<div id="items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

I want to write some functions to affect each one using jQuery. Something like...

```
$(".item").click(function(i){
    i.hide();
});
```

Can someone give me a brief explanation how to make this work? Should I use .each()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works too without the each

```
$(".item").click(function() {
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this :)

```
$(".item").live('click',function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Any reason you changed `click` (or equivalent `bind`) to `live`? That changes the behaviour (`live` makes it so it will automatically bind to anything matching that selector into the future), so you should have a good reason to do that.

Comment: Also you don't need the `$(...)` around `this` (`this` is already a jQuery object).

Comment: Actually, ignore what I said about $. I don't know how it worked for me, but it apparently didn't work for others, and the [documentation tells you](http://api.jquery.com/bind) to explicitly wrap with $.

Comment: First I personally think $(..) is required, second I use .live more often given it's disadvantages but I never said my solution was the best :) but on @float's problems my solution worked fine :)

Answer (score 2):

(a) The documentation is clear on what the event handlers do.

(b) Like most jquery methods (and the exceptions all state specifically that they are exceptions), `.click` will be applied to each member of the set selected by the jquery object. So, no, you don't need to use `.each` if you want each of them to have the same function installed as the event handler.

(c) `this` or `event.currentTarget`  (or in your example, `i.currentTarget`) is the way to access the dom node which is the recipient of the event. `i` in your example will be the event object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.item').each(function(index){
    $(this).bind('click', function(){
        $(this).hide();
        //alert("hiding item nr: "+index);
    });
});
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you don't need `each` because jQuery automatically applies the action to each of the elements matched. You only need each if you actually want to loop over the elements (for example, if you wanted to `alert` each element, as shown in the example on the [each documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/)). Also, you don't need `.bind('click', ...)`; using `.click(...)` as the OP had is sufficient, and cleaner.

Comment: yes I know. I just thought, maybe one want to know the index. therefor the alert is as comment. And the bind('click',... I am using for the reason of better readability... I am not doing this since yesterday mgiuca :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use each, like this:

```
$(".item").each(function(){
   //Here, use $(this) to reference current element 
   $(this).hide();
});
```

`.each()` applies the function you pass to every element in the matched selector, referencing with `this` the current element.

It has optional parameters and other things. Here you can learn more: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: That will hide each item, rather than setting a click event handler on each item as the code in the question is attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

This hopefully does what you want. Let us know if that works, hope that helps.

```
$(".item").each(function(){
     $(this).click(function () {
         $(this).hide();
     });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to use `$(this)` instead of `i` inside the handler function. The argument to the handler is an [event object](http://api.jquery.com/click/), which contains information about the event (such as the mouse coordinates where it was clicked, and other stuff). Probably somewhere in `i` is the object that was clicked, but you can access "whichever object was clicked" much more easily using `this`.

You don't have to use `each` because jQuery automatically binds the handler to each of the elements matched by the query `".item"`.

```
$(".item").click(function(i){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

**Edit**: Added `$(...)` around `this`, as instructed in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind). (For some reason, it worked for me without the $, but apparently you need it.)

Comment: @float Hmm, well it worked for me, but the documentation says you are correct, so I changed my answer.

Comment: It's IMPOSSIBLE that it worked without $(), cause `div` dom elment doesn't have a native `hide()` method

Comment: @Edgar: Ouch, yeah I tried it again and it didn't work without $. No idea what was going on. Mea culpa.

Comment: @mgiuca Don't worry, it happens :D